# Trouble with Submitting Custom Data to a Login Form

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I have a login form that I would like to send custom POST values to. The URL looks like this: site.com/administrator/index.php

There is a login form on that page that looks like this:

```
    function setFocus() {
        document.login.username.select();
        document.login.username.focus();
    }
<body onload="javascript:setFocus()">

<div id="border-top" class="h_green"></div>
<div id="content-box">
    <div class="padding">
        <div id="element-box" class="login">
            <div class="t"></div>
            <div class="m">
                <h1></h1>
                <dl id="system-message"></dl>
                <div id="section-box">
                    <div class="t"></div>
                    <div class="m">
                        <form id="form-login" style="clear: both;" name="login" method="post" action="index.php">
                            <p id="form-login-username">
                                <label for="modlgn_username"></label>
                                <input id="modlgn_username" class="inputbox" type="text" size="15" name="username"></input>
                            </p>
                            <p id="form-login-password"></p>
                            <p id="login-error-message"></p>
                            <p></p>
                            <p id="form-login-lang" style="clear: both;"></p>
                            <div class="button_holder"></div>
                            <div class="clr"></div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" style="border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" value="com_login" name="option"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" value="login" name="task"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="3229cc4ec7d0ca37d4f0ff08ebca8251"></input>
```

I analyzed the requests that the browser was making when submitting a form with httpFox, and here is the result( this is the POST data when putting in das as the username and add as password):

```
username=das&passwd=asd&lang=&option=com_login&task=login&3229cc4ec7d0ca37d4f0ff08ebca8251=1
```

This is not an ordinary login box, and so, I do not know how to proceed. What I would like to do is be able to send requests from my browser as if I was submitting the form, but I am not sure what the final query looks like or where to send it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Read some [php form tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+form+tutorial)

Comment: Your index.php needs to handle the data sent to it. This is done but using the $_POST variable i.e. $uname = $_POST['username'];  The last hidden value is going to cause you problems if the 'name' changes with  each form.